# Pycaret Model Predict

Tags: python, pycaret

I don't have too much experience with pycaret but I'm figuring things out slowly but surely. I'm trying to figure out how to have a model predict a value, not in the data I give it but rather outside the data. For example, I have data that is ordered by date from 2020-9-30 to 2020-10-30. Once I provide the model with this data, it predicts values from 2020-9-30 to 2020-10-30, but I want it to predict 2020-10-31. I can't figure out how to make that work. Please can someone who knows how to solve this problem, if there is a solution, help me.

P.S If that was confusing, please ask me to clarify  Thanks!

This is what I'm using to predict the values, asset is a 250x7 data frame. When the code runs, it prints a 250x2 data frame that is an exact copy of the asset data. But I want it to print one new value in the label column

```
modelpredict = predict_model(final_bestmodel, data=asset)

mpdf = pd.DataFrame(modelpredict, columns = ['Date', 'Label'])

mpdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do classification or regression you can use `predict_model(best_model, data=data_unseen)` and pass new data to the `data` argument e.g. if you want to prediction value on 2020-10-31 you need to provide all variables that you use in the training phase to model. You can find documentation from [here](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/regression.html#pycaret.regression.predict_model) and tutorial from [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20Regression.ipynb)

If you do forecasting you can also use `predict_model(best_model, fh = 24)` and pass the number of forecasting horizons to `fh` argument, and don't forget to finalize the model before the last prediction. It will forecast `fh` step beyond the latest date in training data. You can find documentation from [here](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/time_series.html#pycaret.time_series.predict_model) and tutorial from [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/tree/master/tutorials/time_series/forecasting)